# Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `root` are not valid - Nextjs & Prisma

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, next.js, prisma

I've been working on a Next.js project using Prisma as the DB.

When trying to establish a connection to my Database, I'm Getting an authentication failed error in the terminal even though my username and password are correct.

For Example, My user name is “**root**” and password is “**mypassword**” below is the database url for this in my ".env" file

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:mypassword@localhost:3306/nextapp`

When I use this in my .env file and call it in the prisma schema file i’m getting the below error.

**“Authentication failed against database server at localhost, the provided database credentials for root are not valid.”**

But, I was able to test my connection using mysql in terminal, also using “Mysql ace application". I’m able to connect to my db with those.

Not sure why it's not working inside the next.js project.

Please help

Comment: Back up your `prisma` folder and .env file. Generate from scratch using CLI `npx prisma init --datasource-provider mysql` and add your db URL to the .env file. Run `npx prisma studio` for DB operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response @GolamrabbiAzad, By following your instructions, I'm able to view the table opened in my browser in this path - "http://localhost:5555/".

But, I'm still getting the same error in my terminal - here is the screenshot https://i.ibb.co/mq1qWtV/Screenshot-2023-12-30-at-6-12-24-PM.png

Comment: Alright, now it is confirmed that this error coming from your DB, and the `root` user needs to be granted to perform queries.